# absolute path for php unlink function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, unlink

**PHP**

```
    <?php

$deleteImage = null;

if(isset($_POST["deleteImage"])){$deleteImage = $_POST["deleteImage"];}

unlink($deleteImage);



?>
```

I'm sending `$deleteImage` to the php page via ajax.and I got following

**Jquery response OUTPUT**

```
$deleteImage =  '../pard_media/Upload/upload/23.jpg';
```

There is a image called 23.jpg in my upload directory. but images does to delete .Do i want to add absolute path to delete the image ?

My AJAX

```
$.ajax({

   url: "../pard_media/Upload/delete.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: "deleteImage=" + data,

   success: function (response) {

   alert(response);

           }
 });
```

Comment: unlink("'".$deleteImage."'");  remove "'" at the beginning and the end of unlink parameter. unlink($deleteImage);

Comment: Whoa, that means anyone can delete an image from your website by posting to your page with a URL of the image they want to delete? Doesn't sound safe. Do you have a database of these images with IDs that you can use? That will make it easier to assign the rights to deleting images, and you can pass IDs instead of the image URLs directly. To answer your question, I'm not sure you can delete images using `unlink` and relative paths. I would always use an absolute URL to make sure I know exactly which file I'm removing.

Comment: @dKen i'll update my ajax code

Comment: I hope you are using A LOT of verification to make sure only valid stuff gets deleted. Because from what I see, anybody can remove ANY file they put into that ajax, and that is a SERIOUS security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better, also safety wise to use an absolute path. But you can get this path dynamically.

E.g. using:

```
getcwd();
```

Depending on where your PHP script is, your variable could look like this:

```
$deleteImage =  getcwd() . '/upload/23.jpg';
```

Comment: Probably you need to use unlink( getcwd(). $deleteImage); but you need to make sure that you only supply the last part (the filename itself) in the JSON.

Comment: i set it but it is return this  unlink(/home/itstec2/public_html/PardTest/pard/pard_media/Upload../pard_media/Upload/upload/971435_10151670690552288_262308133_n.jpg)